# The meaning of the french verb "Zoner" & the adjective "tanqué"

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

In the French song "On fleek", Eva said "Reste avec tes grosses folles, t'es bon qu'à zoner", so what's the meaning of "zoner" in this phrase and in general too and what's the meaning of the adjective "tanqué" as well..in "t'es tanqué"?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to FSE. It's better that each question asks one thing, especially if the queries are not related somehow. For instance one question for zoner and another for tanqué.

Answer (score 1):

> 'zoner' means to loiter, to hang around doing nothing.

> 'tanqué' means standing still, stationary.

In the song it's taking a figurative meaning. She says she wants to grow up, she's got goals, a family, a team, etc... while he's good only to loiter and do nothing. She tells him to stay with his fans, with his crazies, while she takes off.

Comment: @Jonathan..thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate that but can I ask you another question in the same song  "Tu kiffes trop la mala" does this sentence means you really like to party...thanks again

Comment: I'd be happy to help @Zuko but it's better if you start a new question for that one.

Comment: @Zuko If Jonathan's answer is Ok, you should choose it.

Answer (score 1):

Complément de l'excellente réponse de @Jonathan :

Zoner :

> (Intransitif) (Argot) Mener une existence marginale, vivre en zonard.

> (Intransitif) (Argot)(Par extension) Flâner, errer, se déplacer sans but précis.

Source : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zoner

Tanquer (régionalisme)

> (Provence) (Occitanie) S’immobiliser, installer, rester planté.

> (Provence) (Vulgaire) Se faire quelqu’un, baiser.

Source : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tanquer